# Ошибка: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032" errorID=2032]

Tags: apache-flex

[image: ошибка при инсталляции]

Во время инсталляции Apache Flex вылетает ошибка:

> [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032" errorID=2032]

Гуглил и нечего не нашёл

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Я первый раз в жизни прогу ставлю. Я не имею понятия что это за ошибка. Просто во время установки вылетает такая вещь. В гугле нашёл что пару людей жаловались с этой проблемой но ответа как зафиксить нету